# Leaflet points off from correct spot on map

Tags: leaflet, epsg

I am working on updating our map from OpenLayers 2 to Leaflet. I have my own set of tiles that are working correctly on OL2 but on leaflet any point I draw seems to be incorrect (further south and east than it should be). The projection is EPSG:4326. Since the points aren’t drastically far off from the actual point I am not sure what is going wrong. I used https://epsg.io/map#srs=4326 to find the static lat long.

Through trial and error I noticed that the closer to the northwest corner of the map I got the amount the point was off was smaller. I also was able to “solve” the problem by updating the tile size from 512 to 512.58 even though the images are 512px.

I put a code example up on glitch since there is a large amount of code:
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/jagged-cricket
client.js holds the pertinent code. At the top of the file you can toggle comments for the two declarations `tileSize` to see the difference.

I am trying to figure out why the GPS points are incorrect and what I can do to fix it.